# Replace\remove character in string

Tags: c++, string

```
string DelStr = "I! am! bored!";
string RepStr = "10/07/10"
```

I want to delete all '!' on DelStr and I want to replace all '/' with '-' on the RepStr string.

Is there any way to do this without doing a loop to go through each character?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ character replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820394/c-character-replace)

Comment: No, removal was not addressed there.

Comment: however you do it, a loop is needed; you may not do it, the called method surely will.

Comment: @larsmans: It covers part of his question and the solutions are applicable to both his problems (delete is replace with whitespace or empty string). In this case, the question should be merged.

Comment: Delete is not replace with an empty string in C++. See my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy) the exclamations:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::string result;
std::remove_copy(delStr.begin(), delStr.end(), std::back_inserter(result), '!');
```

Alternatively, if you want to print the string, you don't need the `result` variable:

```
#include <iostream>

std::remove_copy(delStr.begin(), delStr.end(),
                 std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout), '!');
```

[Replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) slashes with dashes:

```
std::replace(repStr.begin(), repStr.end(), '/', '-');
```

Comment: Note that this will mean that if you try and use result.size(), you will get the size of destStr, as result will also contain additional null characters.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
clrscr();
char a[200],ch,ch1;
int temp=0,i,j,x,len,z,f,k=0;
cout<<"Enter String: ";
cin.getline(a,150);
len=strlen(a);
cout<<"\n\nLength Of String: ";
cout<<len;
cout<<"\n\n\nReplace: ";
cin>>ch;
cout<<"\n\nReplace with: ";
cin>>ch1;
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
if(ch==a[i])
{
temp=a[i];
a[i]=ch1;
}
}
cout<<"\n\nUpdated String: ";
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
cout<<a[i];
}
getch();
}

Example: 
Enter String: Hey! How Are You.
Replace: H
Replace with: m
Output: mey! mow Are You.

(Note: Every character has its ascii code. Such as 'H' and 'h' are two different characters.)
```

Comment: iostream.h was replaced with iostream with std namepsace and conio.h is not standard c/c++ file.