# how to use cin.ignore to ignore specified character in C++

Tags: c++, keyboard

I want to use cin.ignore() to get my data from keyboard.
example: I input a string "12/12/2015". How can I ignore "/" to get my data such a string as "12122015".Because I read in book (How to program c++, deitel), they used cin.ignore to do that, but now I can't find out where it is?
Thanks for your helps!!!

Comment: [`istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) ignores characters based on their **position**.  Not their content.

Comment: thank you, i understood after reading the code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read a fixed amount of characters and then use `cin.ignore(1)` to skip the following character, but it is not very elegant. If I was you, I'd use `getline`, and set an end-of-line delimiter to be `'/'`:

```
string day, month, year;

getline(cin, day, '/');
getline(cin, month, '/');
// and the rest is assumed to be the year
cin >> year;

string date = day + month + year;
cout << date << '\n';
```

However, if you *really* want to use `cin.ignore`, here's how (I think, haven't used C strings in a while, seems to give the right results):

```
char day[3], month[3], year[5];

cin.get(day, 3);
cin.ignore(1);
cin.get(month, 3);
cin.ignore(1);
cin.get(year, 5);

string date = string(day) + string(month) + string(year);
cout << date << '\n';
```

Comment: thanks a lot, your explanation help me very much, but I am constructing a date class and I want to allow the user to input a string mm/dd/yyyy in the console windows instead of inputting dd, then mm and then yyyy. At this point I have problem with dividing the string to get my data "ddmmyyyy". do you have any idea

Comment: The code shown should just work with a single string

Answer (score 2):

You have to process it manually

cin.ignore works another way.
[See cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)

> **istream& ignore (streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF);**
>
> Extracts characters from the input sequence and discards them, until either n characters have been extracted, or one compares equal to delim.

May be as trivial solution:[Replace\remove character in string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3882420/1823963)

Comment: i have read this syntax in the internet, but i don't know how to apply it in my problem