# How to get C++ to read a file

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++. This is an assignment I am completing therefore I must use a the function problem1() as there is another function that I need to create to find max and min. The following text file was provided to me for the assignment.

I am having a hard time with having the program read a text file that contains a set of numbers such as the following :

[253, 676, 114]

[527, 160, 277]

[364, 193, 169]

[246, 651, 378]

[536, 479, 695]

[569, 548, 83]

my code is :

```
using namespace std;

void problem1(string);

int main()
{
    string s= "data2.txt";
    problem1(s);
    return 0;
}
    
void problem1(string s)
    {
        double num, sum = 0, avg;
        int count=0;
        ifstream file;
        file.open(s);
        if (file.is_open())
        {
            while(file>>num)
            {
                sum= sum + num;
                count++;
                
            }
    avg= sum/count;
        
        cout <<"Average is " << avg << endl;
        file.close();
        
    }

    }
```

It works for text files that contine the numbers without [].

For example:

text file contains the following..

1

2

3

4

5

and  finds the avg of 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use cin.ignore to ignore specified character in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145999/how-to-use-cin-ignore-to-ignore-specified-character-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at one line of the input file, then you will see the following. It consists of

- opening square bracket
- first number
- comma
- second number
- comma
- third number
- closing bracket

If you want to read the line and all lines in a file, then you must read everything. For the character that you are not interested in, you could use a `char temp` temporary variable and read those characters into it, like so:

```
fileStream >> temp >> first >> temp >> second >> temp >> third >> temp;
```

Of course you can use also more "speaking" and separate variables like so:

```
fileStream >> openingBracket >> first >> comma1 >> second >> comma2 >> third >> closingBracket;
```

Then you could also validate in an `if` statement, if the variables contain the expected values:

```
if (openingBracket == '[' and comma1 == ',' and comma2 ==',' and closingBracket==']') ....
```

But forget this at the moment.

So, now we know how to read a line. If we want to read all lines, we put the above statement in a `while`. This will then run, until it hits an End-Of-File or some other error occurs.

In the while loop body, you can do your calculations. And after the while loop body, you can output the resulting average as a double value.

Please note:

- The constructor of the `std::ifstream` opens the file for you automatically. The destructor will close it automatically
- The bool operator of the streams is overwritten. It returns, if the state is ok, or if one of the status bits is set. Therefore `if (fileStream)` is sufficient for a check.
- the extractor operator `>>` returns a reference to the stream. So, if you write `fileStream >> openingBracket` then the result will be "fileStream", this will be used for the next extraction operation `fileStream >> first` and so on and so on. At the end, you will have something similar like `while(fileStream)`. And this will run until "eof" or other failure bits are set. (See bool operator above).

Your whole program could then look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void problem1(std::string fileName) {

    // Open the file
    std::ifstream fileStream{ fileName };

    // Check, if everything is ok with the stream
    if (fileStream) {
        // These are dummy variables
        char openingBracket{}, comma1{}, comma2{}, closingBracket{};
        // The values in one line
        int first{}, second{}, third{};

        // For summing up and claculating the average
        int sum{}, counter{};

        // Read data, as long as there are any
        while (fileStream >> openingBracket >> first >> comma1 >> second >> comma2 >> third >> closingBracket) {

            // Do the necessary calculations
            sum += first + second + third;
            counter += 3;
        }
        // Output avaerage value as double
        std::cout << "Average is " << static_cast<double>(sum) / static_cast<double>(counter) << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "data2.txt";
    problem1(s);
    return 0;
}
```

---

---

**Edit:**

Searching for max and min:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

void problem1(std::string fileName) {

    // Open the file
    std::ifstream fileStream{ fileName };

    // We want to know the min max value
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();


    // Check, if everything is ok with the stream
    if (fileStream) {
        // These are dummy variables
        char openingBracket{}, comma1{}, comma2{}, closingBracket{};
        // The values in one line
        int first{}, second{}, third{};

        // For summing up and claculating the average
        int sum{}, counter{};

        // Read data, as long as there are any
        while (fileStream >> openingBracket >> first >> comma1 >> second >> comma2 >> third >> closingBracket) {

            // Do the necessary calculations
            sum += first + second + third;
            counter += 3;

            if (first > max) max = first;
            if (second > max) max = second;
            if (third > max) max = third;
            if (first < min) min = first;
            if (second < min) min = second;
            if (third < min) min = third;

        }
        // Output average value as double
        std::cout << "Average is " << static_cast<double>(sum) / static_cast<double>(counter)
            << "\nMax = " << max << "\nMin = " << min << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I see. Thank you so much for clearing that up that was very helpful!

Comment: Could I use the same format to find max and min?

Comment: Yes. I edited my answer. Please see the additional code.